# How would you fix Xcode Firebase Integration With SwiftUI saying: format:@"`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find "

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I am clueless as to what I need to fix this problem.

I have Firebase running in my workspace in Xcode and I followed the Firebase instructions which are:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
  [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()
return true
   }
}
```

But the issue is when I run the project the simulation is white. And goes to FirApp.m and says the following code.

```
    if (!options) {
[NSException raise:kFirebaseCoreErrorDomain
            format:@"`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find "
                   @"a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one "
                   @"from %@.",
                   kPlistURL];
```

I was following CodingWithChris with this tutorial --> https://youtu.be/1HN7usMROt8?t=2363

Comment: I have yes GoogleService-Info.plist in my project, but I try again to make a new one and see what happens. I will tell you if it works.

Comment: Should I look to fix info.plist or GoogleService-Info.plist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set different Google-Service-info-plist file according to environment in iOS Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516306/how-to-set-different-google-service-info-plist-file-according-to-environment-in)

Comment: let me check it our

Comment: what is Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Comment: An answer will depend on how the *GoogleService-Info.plist* was added to your project (did you drag and drop it into your project files in the lefthand column?) and whether the old (UIKit App Delegate) or new (SwiftUI) app lifecycle was selected. Did you manually add the AppDelegate code as shown in the question or was it there when you created the project?

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the GoogleService-Info.plist does not have a look like this GoogleService-Info.plist(5) when you download it again or it will not work.

To deal with black screen the error was the following:

```
Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
```

In the storyboard, make sure to uncheck the "Is initial View Controller" because it might be getting confused with multiple view controllers.
In the app go to app target and press the Info tab. There is minus or add in the value of "Main storyboard file base name" you need to use the minus to make it go away. Then on the "General tab" clear do the same thing for "Main Interface".

Comment: Glad the error was caused by a typo and corrected! However, this answer may send some users the wrong direction - most apps *need* an initial viewController and the app will never get confused with multiple viewControllers as that's the nature of iOS Development. So unchecking it is perfectly fine *as long you define the initial view controller in code*. If you don't, the app may behave erratically and may not start at all. Just a heads up for future readers.